# upcasting - while calling the subcalss object

Tags: java, casting

A simple upcasting is going on where the sub calss(dog)'s object is referenced by its super class(Animal)...

Why i am not able to call the method 'callme2()'

CODE:-

```
class Animal 
    { 
        public void callme()
        {
            System.out.println("In callme of Animal");
        }

    }

    class Dog extends Animal 
    { 
        public void callme()
        {
            System.out.println("In callme of Dog");
        }

        public void callme2()
        {
            System.out.println("In callme2 of Dog");
        }
    }

    class upcasting
    {
        public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
        {
            Animal a = new Dog();     
    a.callme(); //-In call me of Dog       
    a.callme2(); // - error why ?
     }
    }
```

Comment: Because the `a` variable is a reference of Animal type and not of `Dog` type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `a` is assigned to superclass `Animal`

You can call the methed as follow:

```
((Dog)a).callme2()
```

Comment: a is assigned to superclass Animal then how it is able to call the 'callme 'method of dog because of overriding .. ? am i right ?

Comment: @rd4code, you are right.Call to `callme` is resolved at runtime ( dynamic binding ). Refer http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/what-is-static-and-dynamic-binding-in.html